# Unable to Execute a Call to Pylint from a Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, pylint

When the function below is called, the execution hangs up at
`output=$(pylint r -n ${pathfilename})`, and does not process to the `echo` statements

```
# Python stuff
function pylint () {
    argument1="$1"
    clear && printf '\e[3J'
    # Extract the path and file name for pylint when method name is passed
    pathfilename=`echo ${argument1} | sed 's/::.*//'`
    output=$(pylint -r n ${pathfilename})
    echo "${output}"
    echo "${pathfilename}"
}
```

Comment: You are calling a function inside function

Comment: `output=$(docker exec -t orch-$USER pylint -r n ${pathfilename})` this call works just fine in another function.

Comment: If you mean to call pylint but not print reports, it should be

    `pylint -r n ${pathfilename}`

Comment: @yashbagarka `$()` is not a function call, it starts a subshell, and it's a legitimate thing to do here.

Comment: The name of the command and function was same - A.L.Flanagan

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your own function recursively, instead of (I assume) a `pylint` command. Name your wrapper function something different to `pylint` so it calls the command and does not call itself. Or add a path to the pylint command call as in

```
output=$(/usr/bin/pylint r -n ${pathfilename})
```

Maybe seize the opportunity to reduce typing and call the function `pyl` or so.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks for pointing out the recursive part. It should have been a hint since execution went into a infinite loop at that line.